# Issue customizing the behaviour and appearance of the status bar

Tags: android, android-statusbar

I'm implementing some user interfaces of an android project. There are situations related to the status bar that I'm struggling to implement.

(1) I have a screen with a scrolling status bar. That means the status bar should be scrolled up/down with main content. (The behaviour is similar, as the scroll bar is enclosed inside a ScrollView). Is it possible to do?

(2) When the scroll bar color is white, the content of the scroll bar is not visible since they are also in white color. But since Marshmallow(api 23 and above) we can use `windowLightStatusBar`  attribute to make it use dark foreground. I couldn't find a way to do this below api 23.

Any suggestions would be appreciated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes. Put your status bar (e.g. a Toolbar) inside the `ScrollView`

2) There's no way to do this if the device is running API 22 and below.

Comment: its not the toolbar, status bar is the one on the top that shows time and notification icons..

Comment: Then no, you can't scroll that, unless you implement some weird mash of full screen layout with a scroll listener that toggles that full screen layout when you reach the top of the `ScrollView`